# Inyectar vista parcial desde el shared

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET MVC 6
Quiero realizar inyección de una partialview.  Hasta ahora hago el llamado y me lo carga en pantalla, sólo que en lugar de cargar la partialview también me carga el menú de la página completa.

La forma en que trabaja: un botón con función onClick llama al controlador y lo envia al servicio de ajax. El controlador realiza a consulta y lo recibe la funcción funSuccess del ajax.

Index.cshtml

```
@model.ViewModel.VistaViewModel
@Html.Partial("opin/_seccionDatosIdentificacion")
@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.IdUsuario, new { @Id = "hdnIdUsuario" })
<script type="text/javascript">
var opinController = new window.opinController();
</script>
```

_seccionDatosIdentificacion.cshtml (Esta vista la tengo en la carpeta de shared)

```
@model.ViewModel.VistaViewModel 
<div class="panel panel-primary" id="divSeccion1">
 //Contenido de la partialView
 <button onclick="opinController.btnCargarIdentificaion()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mostrar identificación anterior <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>                                
 <button onclick="opinController.btnGuardarIdentificaion()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Guardar y continuar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span></button>
 </div>
```

opinController.js

```
var btnCargarIdentificaion = function () {
    getIdentificacionAnterior();
}

var getIdentificacionAnterior = function () {
    objOpinService.getProcesoUsuario($("#hdnIdUsuario").val(),
                                    "/opin/GetDatosIdentificacionAnterior",
                                    function (data) {
                                        onSuccessGet(data)
                                        $("#divSeccion1").html(data);
                                    },
                                    onErrorSave);
}

return { btnCargarIdentificaion: btnCargarIdentificaion }
```

opinService.js

```
var getProcesoUsuario = function (id, actionGetDetalle, funSuccess, funError) {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: actionGetDetalle,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: id,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            funSuccess(data);                  
        },
        error: function (error) {
            funError(error);
        }
    });
}

return { getProcesoUsuario: getProcesoUsuario }
```

OpinController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetDatosIdentificacionAnterior([FromBody]int idUsuario)
    {
        ViewData[Generales.TituloPrincipalName] = this.appResourcesServices.GetTitlePRO492(this.GetLenguaje).Message;
        ViewData[Generales.SubTituloPrincipalName] = this.appResourcesServices.GetSubTitleOPIN(this.GetLenguaje).Message;

        OpinRelProcesoViewModel procesoViewModel = getIdentificacionUsuarioViewModel(idUsuario);
        return PartialView("_seccionDatosIdentificacion", procesoViewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo sería necesario poner en tu vista `_seccionDatosIdentificacion.cshtml`:

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
```

Comment: podrías ponerlo como `Layout = null;`